# Layover in Istanbul with infants

Tags: children, layovers, istanbul

This Saturday we'll be travelling with a layover at Istanbul Atatürk Airport.  The layover is just under 3 hours.  We'll be travelling with two infants (under 1 year old). Are their any baby-friendly facilities there?  I am specifically interested in baby changing facilities and some relatively quiet place for feeding (spoon/bottle feeding, not breast-feeding, so privacy is not too important).

**Edit:** It may be worth noting that we'll be in Istanbul airport at night/early morning.  Our flight gets to Istanbul at 4:20 am and the connecting flight leaves at 7:05.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going through my old questions...

We ended up not needing any special facilities.  The waiting area near the gate for our connecting flight had a baby changing room right next to the toilets. Considering the time of day, it was relatively quiet, so the children slept most of the time anyway.

Of course, this answer is now probably outdated, because Turkish has moved all their flights to the new airport recently.

Answer (score 1):

I would have expected you to have posted an answer from personal experience by now but instead [Tavport.com](http://www.ataturkairport.com/en-EN/airportguide/Pages/Lounges.aspx) has details of baby care rooms in Lounges:
>

> ### International Terminal
>
> **"primeclass" Lounge**
>
> Designed in plain and sophisticated style, the Lounge offers ultimate
>   comfort 24/7 with facilities including self-service buffet options of
>   fresh and tasty complimentary snacks, **kids room**, internet Access,
>   Playstation, TV, tablet computers, newspapers and magazines, shower
>   rooms and personal care products.
>
> Location: One floor below the Food Court after the passport control
>   point at the International Terminal Departures Floor
>
> **Turkish Airlines Lounge Istanbul Departure**
>
> Ranked as one of the world’s top ten private passenger lounges, “
>   Lounge Istanbul Departure” with a covered area of 6000 square meters,
>   and capable of seating 1,100 people. The lounge provides unique tastes
>   of Turkish and World dishes not found in other airline lounges.The
>   lounge, where the modern is blended with the traditional, offers a set
>   of atmospheres both tranquil and filled with entertainment to suit
>   your desires. A great range of services and activities— including a
>   realistic racetrack providing the excitement of a car race, video game
>   consoles, a cutting-edge golf simulator, private resting and showering
>   areas, media wall, cinema, **a play area for children**, a library, a pool
>   room, a prayer room, a teleconference hall, and massage service—are at
>   arm’s reach.
>
> **Turkish Airlines Lounge Istanbul Arrival**
>
> The lounge occupies a 300 square-meter area and provides seating
>   capacity for 350 people. The lounge provides many services such us
>   library, an always-current local and international magazine and
>   newspaper section, Wi-Fi connectivity, and media walls, power outlets
>   for your electronic devices. Also awaiting you at the Lounge Istanbul
>   Arrival are relaxation areas equipped with shower stalls, **a changing
>   room**, and an ironing room with staff to tend to your clothes that need
>   ironing. The lounge accepts passengers from 5:00 a.m. to 12:30 p.m.
>   local time and operates from 5:00 a.m. to 1:00 p.m.
>
> **Comfort Lounge**
>
> Open 24/7, the Lounge offers tasty snacks buffet and facilities
>   including music system with personal headphones, wireless internet
>   access, tablet computers, TV, daily newspapers, monthly and weekly
>   magazines to ensure that passengers can relax and enjoy the time
>   before their flights. In addition, showers and massage chairs are also
>   offered in the Lounge for that ultimate comfort.
>
> Location: Mezzanine floor after the passport control point at
>   International Terminal Departures Floor within Istanbul Atatürk
>   Airport.
>
> **SkyTeam Lounge**
>
> Operated by TAV “primeclass” CIP Service, SkyTeam Lounge adds value to
>   the travel experience of Elite Plus, First and Business class
>   passengers of SkyTeam Member Airlines with the services it offers
>   24/7. The business center of the 350 square meter Lounge which can
>   accommodate up to 90 passengers at a time, is equipped with facilities
>   including Wi-Fi access and printer and the eating section presents an
>   open buffet service. The Lounge has more than 70 electric power
>   sockets, a reading area and a separate TV room.
>
> Location: Next to Gate 223 after the passport control point at the
>   Istanbul Atatürk Airport International Terminal.
>
> **Emirates Lounge**
>
> Operated by TAV “primeclass”, the Lounge is open during the flight
>   times of Emirates Airlines. Emirates Lounge is exclusively designed
>   and overlooks the apron. The small toys, personal and hygienic kits
>   given as a present to the young guests at the entrance make **both
>   children and their families** happy. Pre-flight comfort is guaranteed
>   with facilities including TV, Wi-Fi, daily newspapers, weekly and
>   monthly magazines, business corner, delicious self-service buffet and
>   bar. The Lounge also offers shower facilities, a prayer room, separate
>   WC, disabled WC and **baby changing room**.
>
> Location: Next to Gate 223 after the passport control point at the
>   Istanbul Atatürk Airport International Terminal. İts closing after
>   last flight (19:25)
>
> Monday, Wednesday, Thursday opening : 15:20
>
> Tuesday, Friday, Saturday opening : 12:20
>
> **HSBC Club Lounge**
>
> Designed to give maximum comfort to the customers while waiting their
>   flights at the airport. Seating capacity is 80 people. The Lounge is
>   open 7/24 offering a relaxing atmosphere with facilities including
>   fresh and daily food & beverages, Wi-Fi, daily newspapers, weekly and
>   monthly magazines, PC, TV, ATM, mobile phone charge units, locked case
>   units, WC. HSBC Credit Card and Priority Pass Card holders can benefit
>   from the Lounge services.
>
> Location: One floor up to the Food Court after the passport control at
>   the International Terminal Departures Floor.
>
> ### Domestic Terminal
>
> "primeclass" Lounge
>
> Open 24/7, the Lounge offers a spacious and quite atmosphere
>   overlooking the apron and amenities such as daily newspapers, weekly
>   and monthly magazines, an open buffet, cable and wireless internet
>   access and complimentary use of tablet computers. The Lounge stands
>   out as the only one at the airport with an outdoor terrace area.
>
> Location: Mezzanine Floor after the security control at the Departures
>   Floor at Atatürk Airport Domestic Terminal.
>
> Turkish Airlines Lounge Istanbul Domestic
>
> The lounge occupies a 3500 square-meter area and provides seating
>   capacity for 350 people. Besides all the comforts and modern
>   technological facilities you might need, awaiting you as soon as you
>   enter the lounge are delicious catering offerings.The lounge provides
>   many services such us an always-current local and international
>   magazine and newspaper section, Wi-Fi connectivity, media walls, power
>   outlets for your electronic devices, private resting and showering
>   areas, media wall, cinema, a **play area for children**, a prayer room, a
>   teleconference hall, and massage service.

My emphasis.